# where can I get Microsoft.Practices.SmartClient.DisconnectedAgent.dll?

Tags: smartclient, scsf

I'm rebuilding a project that uses:

Microsoft.Practices.SmartClient.DisconnectedAgent.dll

And I can't find it anywhere as a download:

- [Smart Client Software Factory – April 2008](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=3BE112CC-B2C1-4215-9330-9C8CF9BCC6FA&displaylang=en) - this creates the folder "SCSF-Apr2008" with a "lib" directory that has lots of "Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.*" DLLs but not the DisconnectedAgent one I need.
- [Smart Client Software Factory - May 2007](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=2B6A10F9-8410-4F13-AD53-05A202FBDB63&displaylang=en&hash=eZSjWtpZSiK0rsK1yqaXs8vJovjnghAAKStFsob8wzWOlTH6qiosIA2oMSxUjcAxHw1X3aT0uJDKG4oM8gUWbw==) - many sources say this download has it but it is actually just a zip file with two .chm files

Does anyone know where I can download **Microsoft.Practices.SmartClient.DisconnectedAgent.dll**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's in [Smart Client Software Factory - May 2007.msi](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=2b6a10f9-8410-4f13-ad53-05a202fbdb63&displaylang=en). did you download *Smart Client Software Factory **Documentation** - May 2007* instead? or didn't you install the whole package / didn't have the required dependencies? you could just extract the file from the msi then (google, or use the [total commander](http://www.ghisler.com/) [msi plus plugin](http://www.totalcmd.net/plugring/msiplus.html) - that's where i'm seeing the file right now)

Comment: nice, I installed the May 2007.msi again and paid more attention this time, at one point it said, "Disabled features requires Guidance Automation Extensions February 2007 CTP which is not present on the computer." so the only thing it installed where the .chm files, great, thanks!